# Set Shadeless As Default Shading

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders

I use Blender mostly for 2D design and animation. I import svg vectors and spend a lot of time setting the material shading to shadeless. I was wondering is there anyway in Blender to set Shadeless as a default shading to save myself time?

[image]

Comment: You could always add a material with fake user to the default cube and save as your startup file.

Answer (score 1):

This won't set a default.. IMO, storing a base shadeless material in a startup file is a good way to go, as Timaroberts suggested...

```
import bpy
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    mat.use_shadeless = True
```

But it will clobber *all* the materials in your Blend file, and make them shadeless, if they can be.